# Need Help: XSLT 1.0 Grouping the descriptions of items

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a problem of grouping some items, in one path (`/catalog/Invoice/InvoiceItem`), based on a description from a different path (`/catalog/TypeDesc`).

Input XML:

```
<catalog>
  <Invoice>
    <InvoiceItem Id="G001">
        <Charge Amount="10.000"/>
    </InvoiceItem>
    <InvoiceItem Id="G002">
        <Charge Amount="5.000"/>
    </InvoiceItem>
    <InvoiceItem Id="G003">
        <Charge Amount="50.000"/>
    </InvoiceItem>
    <InvoiceItem Id="G004">
        <Charge Amount="0.500"/>
    </InvoiceItem>
  </Invoice>

  <TypeDesc PKey="G001" LongDes="Local"/>
  <TypeDesc PKey="G002" LongDes="Local"/>
  <TypeDesc PKey="G003" LongDes="Roaming"/>
  <TypeDesc PKey="G004" LongDes="Local"/>
</catalog>
```

My code is based on example 6.3 from here: http://www.kosek.cz/xml/xslt/seskupovani.html

```
<xsl:for-each select="//InvoiceItem">
 <xsl:sort select="//TypeDesc[@PKey = current()/@Id]/@LongDes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="item" select="//TypeDesc[@PKey = current()/@Id]/@LongDes"/>
 <xsl:if test="not(//TypeDesc[@PKey = preceding-sibling::InvoiceItem/@Id]/@LongDes = $item)">
      <fo:block font-weight="bold">Group: <xsl:value-of select="$item"/></fo:block>
 </xsl:if>
 <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="$item"/></fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

My problem is that the sorting is performed correctly, but the grouping fails.

The expected output should be:

```
Group: Local
Local
Local
Local
Group: Roaming
Roaming
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would help if you made sure your answer is a [mcve] so other people can run it and see your problem. So, bring any information from that link into the question itself.

Comment: Thank you, I made some update.

Comment: The muenchian grouping method will do the trick. Use a `key`, which uses the `Id` attribute and use this key to group your `InvoiceItems`. http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use Muenchian grouping, you only need to cross-reference to the description, here is an example outputting HTML but you can adapt that to output FO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:key name="desc-ref" match="TypeDesc" use="@PKey"/>
  <xsl:key name="item-group" match="InvoiceItem" use="/catalog/TypeDesc[@PKey = current()/@Id]/@LongDes"/>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
      <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceItem[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-group', key('desc-ref', @Id)/@LongDes)[1])]">
          <div>
              <h2>
                  <xsl:value-of select="key('desc-ref', @Id)/@LongDes"/>
              </h2>
              <ul>
                  <xsl:for-each select="key('item-group', key('desc-ref', @Id)/@LongDes)">
                      <li>
                          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@Id, ': ', key('desc-ref', @Id)/@LongDes, '; Amount: ', Charge/@Amount) "/>
                      </li>
                  </xsl:for-each>                  
              </ul>
          </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyN

Comment: Thank you very much for your perfect answer! At first it did not work, but when I changed Transformer from "xalan" into "saxon" it worked fine. I don't know why Xalan just stop executing when reaching first for-each line...

Comment: Do me another favor on how to sum the total charge per each group :-)

Comment: `sum(key('item-group', key('desc-ref', @Id)/@LongDes)/Charge/@Amount)` gives you the sum of each group

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate your help Martin Honnen.